# Any idea how much it costs for 1 Domino license?

Tags: ibm-domino

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Any idea how much it cost per domino license per year?

Comment: Ask IBM. They sell, so they know!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you mean the ibm Collaboration licenses. 
Look here:

[gemini-systems.com](http://estore.gemini-systems.com/ibm/software-license/lotus-collaboration-software/lotus-domino-collaboration-express/)

[stdi.com](http://www.stdi.com/stdi/home.nsf/ws/smbLicense!openDocument)

I give no warranty that this informations are correct (google is my friend).